# How to get the size of a varchar[n] field in one SQL statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, varchar

Suppose that I have a SQL table that has a varchar[1000] field called "Remarks".

I would like to craft a single SQL statement, which when executed, will return 1000, or whatever the size of the varchar field might be changed to in the future.

Something like `SELECT size(Remarks) FROM mytable`.

How do I do this?

Comment: This will depend on the RDBMS you are working on.
But as Neil said you may have to search in the information scheme of your server.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

```
select column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length    
  from information_schema.columns  
 where table_name = 'myTable'
```

Comment: you could specify additional clause `AND column_name = 'Remarks'` if you want to filter only one column out.

Comment: Just FYI, this is a MySQL specific query.

Comment: @pickypg: The question is for SQL Server 2008.

Comment: `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is an ANSI standard thing - not MySQL or SQL Server specific at all !

Comment: to filter by a particular database schema add: `AND table_schema = 'mydatabase'`

Answer (score 36):

On SQL Server specifically:

```
SELECT DATALENGTH(Remarks) AS FIELDSIZE FROM mytable
```

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx)

Comment: This statement returns the length of the data that has already been input.  I want the size of the data that the field will hold.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 20):

For SQL Server (2008 and above):

```
SELECT COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('mytable'), 'Remarks', 'PRECISION');
```

COLUMNPROPERTY returns information for a column or parameter (id, column/parameter, property). The PRECISION property returns the length of the data type of the column or parameter.

[COLUMNPROPERTY documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/columnproperty-transact-sql)

Answer (score 10):

This will work on SQL SERVER...

```
SELECT COL_LENGTH('Table', 'Column')
```

Comment: Worth noting that this will return the length in *bytes* so you'll have to halve it for `NVARCHAR` or `NCHAR` for example. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/col-length-transact-sql

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the TOTAL size of the column and hit this article, my solution is based off of MarcE's.

```
SELECT sum(DATALENGTH(your_field)) AS FIELDSIZE FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a function for calculating max valid length for varchar(Nn):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetMaxVarcharColumnLength] (@TableSchema NVARCHAR(MAX), @TableName NVARCHAR(MAX), @ColumnName VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT character_maximum_length FROM information_schema.columns  
            WHERE table_schema = @TableSchema AND table_name = @TableName AND column_name = @ColumnName);
END
```

Usage:

```
IF LEN(@Name) > [dbo].[GetMaxVarcharColumnLength]('person', 'FamilyStateName', 'Name') 
            RETURN [dbo].[err_Internal_StringForVarcharTooLong]();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length    
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where table_name = 'Table1'
```

Answer (score 0):

For t-SQL I use the following query for varchar columns (shows the collation and is_null properties):

```
SELECT
    s.name
    , o.name as table_name
    , c.name as column_name
    , t.name as type
    , c.max_length
    , c.collation_name
    , c.is_nullable
FROM
    sys.columns c
    INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON (o.object_id = c.object_id)
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON (s.schema_id = o.schema_id)
    INNER JOIN sys.types t ON (t.user_type_id = c.user_type_id)
WHERE
    s.name = 'dbo'
    AND t.name IN ('varchar') -- , 'char', 'nvarchar', 'nchar')
ORDER BY
    o.name, c.name
```

Comment: Please be aware that this will display the max_length in bytes, meaning you'll get 'double' sizes for NVARCHAR columns.

Answer (score 0):

For MS SQL Server this will return column length:

```
SELECT COL_LENGTH('dbo.mytable', 'Remarks') AS Result;
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server, instead of SIZE we can use LEN rest everything given in question is fine. LEN returns number of characters, not sure I should call it eye friendly or brain friendly :)

```
SELECT LEN(Remarks) FROM mytable
```

DATALENGTH also works fine as given in other answers but **it returns number of bytes.**

```
SELECT DATALENGTH(Remarks) FROM mytable
```

[Here is documentation reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datalength-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16)