# Data type size of variable in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How to find out the size of data type in sql. For example if i have declared a variable or column as

```
declare @test varchar(255)
```

Then i need the size of the variable data type @test to be shown as 255.

EDIT:Now, I know how to get it for the column, is there any way for variable?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705316/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-varcharn-field-in-one-sql-statement

Comment: @SamDeHaan That's not a duplicate. OP here wants to check for the variable, not a field in a table

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Thanks for that. However, if its not a column and its a variable then what would i do?

Comment: @Adrian: OP said variable or column. You are correct, it's not an exact duplicate, but it is half of his question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [sql_variant_property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178550.aspx).

```
declare @test varchar(255)
set @test = '' --Must assign a value
select sql_variant_property(@test, 'MaxLength')
```

Comment: Just wondering, is there any way to do tat for columns in table variable or temp tables?

Comment: @satish Yes, have a look [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/63853/sql-variant-property).