# TSQL: Find declared length of a variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Data type size of variable in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686525/data-type-size-of-variable-in-sql)

Can you find the declared max length of a variable using `T-SQL`?

For example:

```
DECLARE @myVar varchar(123)
```

-- How can I find the max length of `@myVar` would be 123?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. What is your variable mapping to?

Comment: Googled it and found the answer on Stackoverflow...

Comment: kush, it appears in a proc or query.

Comment: Guffa, thank you for finding it.  I didn't use "data type" or "size" in my Google search.