# Alter column varchar(max) to nvarchar(max) with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column `emailbody` with a datatype of `varchar(max)`, but I want to change it to `nvarchar(max)`.

How to check the `varchar(max)` length in condition?

```
if not exists (select name from syscolumns where name = 'emailbody' and id = OBJECT_ID('emailtb') and xtype = 167 and [length] = ??)
   ALTER TABLE emailtb 
   ALTER COLUMN emailbody nvarchar(max)
```

Comment: Please tag dbms product used, to get better answers faster!

Answer (score 1):

`varchar(max)`, `nvarchar(max)` and `varbinary(max)` are represented as having a length of `-1`. So:

```
if not exists (select name from syscolumns where name = 'emailbody' and id = OBJECT_ID('emailtb') and xtype = 167 and [length] = -1)
ALTER TABLE emailtb ALTER COLUMN emailbody nvarchar(max)
```

For additional details, see [the documentation about sys.columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106.aspx).

Comment: @A.Q - so, what *does* happen? Do you get an error message? Error messages are tremendously useful, whereas your feedback of "not alter the column" isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Altering the following [Source:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705316/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-varcharn-field-in-one-sql-statement)

```
select character_maximum_length    
from information_schema.columns  
where table_name = 'emailtb' AND column_name='emailbody'
```

will get you the length.

in your context:

```
if not exists (select name from syscolumns where name = 'emailbody' and id = OBJECT_ID('emailtb') and xtype = 167 and [length] = (select character_maximum_length from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'emailtb' AND column_name='emailbody'))
ALTER TABLE emailtb ALTER COLUMN emailbody nvarchar(max)
```

quick explanation:

> An information schema view is one of several methods SQL Server provides for obtaining metadata. Information schema views provide an internal, system table-independent view of the SQL Server metadata. Information schema views enable applications to work correctly although significant changes have been made to the underlying system tables. The information schema views included in SQL Server comply with the ISO standard definition for the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

More about information_schema can be found in  [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx)  MSDN article.

Comment: There are some [fairly good arguments against using the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` in SQL Server](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views), the most relevant to this context would be the fact that computed columns are indistinguishable from normal columns, so you can't tell if the varchar(max) column you have found is computed, and thus whether the alter operation will fail.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any strings in your `varchar(max)` column that is longer than 1 GB - 1 byte (1'073'741'823 byte), then you will *not* be able to convert it to `nvarchar(max)`.

Check like this:

```
SELECT emailbody, DATALENGTH(emailbody)
FROM dbo.emailtb 
WHERE DATALENGTH(emailbody) > 1073741823
```

If you find any rows - you'll need to either shorten those `emailbody` contents, or delete those rows, before being able to convert to `nvarchar(max)`