# Fill with spaces a column value in update

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, spaces, nvarchar

How to automatically fill a column with spaces to a pre-determined length in update SQL sentence in **SQL Server 2012**?

I have a table with several columns like

```
Col1 NVARCHAR(10)
Col2 NVARCHAR(100)
Col3 NVARCHAR(200)
Col4 NVARCHAR(50)
```

and more.

If value of column is `NULL or ''`, I update the column with spaces to a pre-determined length (the lenth of the column).

For Col3, if value is `NULL or ''`, spaces to 200 blank space (`' '`)
if value has any characters, `'abcd'`, fill (pad right) to 200 blank spaces. Then, finally 4 not spaces characters and 196 spaces characteres.

For example, for Col1 has length 10.

```
1) Value = NULL    , Col1 value = '         ' (10 spaces)
2) Value = ''      , Col1 value = '         ' (10 spaces)
2) Value = 'abc'   , Col1 value = 'abc      ' (abc and 7 spaces)
```

How can I do that in the UPDATE SQL?

Maybe using

```
select column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length    
  from information_schema.columns  
 where table_name = 'myTable'
```

or

```
SELECT COL_LENGTH('Table', 'Column')
```

More in [How to get the size of a varchar[n] field in one SQL statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705316/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-varcharn-field-in-one-sql-statement)

Comment: @maSTAShuFu ***Legacy*** app using Sql Server for generate CSV file (with blank an spaces format) for extern company. ***Legacy app***

Comment: You would get the behaviour you want if you used nchar instead of nvarchar. But **do not do this**. As it would be a highly inefficient use of resources.

Comment: @MartinSmith not possible, ***Legacy app***

Comment: @Kiquenet, how do you transfer the Data from CSV to sql? SSIS should allow you to transform your data. you can apply trim on the fly. I don't see why you can't. If manual, you can still trim the CSV fields.

Comment: @Kiquenet, why does your _**Legacy app**_ care how the data is stored in the database?  Add the spaces as needed when you query the data.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu legacy App, not time to changes to SSIS. Transfer CSV to SQL Server is a Windows App Legacy, and the same App generate new CSV from SQL Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following, the LEFT is used to keep the length down to the column length, while the space ensures the field is filled with spaces:

```
create table test (col1 varchar(10), col2 varchar(15))
GO

insert into test (col1, col2)
    values   ('', '')
            ,(NULL, NULL)
            ,('abc', 'abc')

UPDATE test
    SET  col1 = LEFT(COALESCE(col1, '') + SPACE(COL_LENGTH('test', 'col1')), COL_LENGTH('test', 'col1'))
        ,col2 = LEFT(COALESCE(col2, '') + SPACE(COL_LENGTH('test', 'col2')), COL_LENGTH('test', 'col2'))
FROM    test

SELECT  *
FROM    test
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you want exactly, but here is what I understand:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    Col1 NVARCHAR(200),
    Col2 NVARCHAR(100),
    Col3 NVARCHAR(200),
    Col4 NVARCHAR(50)
    );
    INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL), ('ABC', NULL, NULL, NULL);
-- You can do the same for the other cols
        UPDATE MyTABLE 
        SET Col1 = REPLICATE(' ', COL_LENGTH('MyTable', 'Col1')/2)
        WHERE Col1 IS NULL;

SELECT *
FROM MyTable;
```

**[Demo](http://rextester.com/RZNTZO72429)**

Update:

Here is how to do it in one statement:

```
UPDATE MyTABLE 
SET Col1 = (SELECT CASE WHEN (Col1 IS NULL) OR (Col1 = '') THEN 
                REPLICATE(' ', COL_LENGTH('MyTable', 'Col1')/2) 
                ELSE Col1 + REPLICATE(' ', (COL_LENGTH('MyTable', 'Col1')/2)- LEN(Col1)) END),
Col2 = (SELECT CASE WHEN (Col2 IS NULL) OR (Col2 = '') THEN 
                REPLICATE(' ', COL_LENGTH('MyTable', 'Col2')/2) 
                ELSE Col2 + REPLICATE(' ', (COL_LENGTH('MyTable', 'Col2')/2)- LEN(Col2)) END),                
Col3 = (SELECT CASE WHEN (Col3 IS NULL) OR (Col3 = '') THEN 
                REPLICATE(' ', COL_LENGTH('MyTable', 'Col1')/2) 
                ELSE Col3 + REPLICATE(' ', (COL_LENGTH('MyTable', 'Col3')/2)- LEN(Col3)) END), 
Col4 = (SELECT CASE WHEN (Col4 IS NULL) OR (Col4 = '') THEN 
                REPLICATE(' ', COL_LENGTH('MyTable', 'Col4')/2) 
                ELSE Col4 + REPLICATE(' ', (COL_LENGTH('MyTable', 'Col4')/2)- LEN(Col4)) END);
```

**[Demo](http://rextester.com/IIVG95227)**

Comment: Why ***COL_LENGTH / 2*** ? divide by 2 ?

Comment: @Kiquenet nvarchar(1) = 2 bytes, not 1, so devide by 2.